# Visual Studio Setup Project - Uninstall is not being called

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

I am preparing setup project for my winform application. I have created an Installer Class and attached into custom action window. I have tried many ways to get uninstall method called but all attempts have failed.

I have not tried to create a separate class installer as I need to read the savedState object during uninstallation

I have run uninstall msi:

```
MSI (s) (04:F4) [17:28:46:819]: Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: Library Manager. Product Version: 1.5.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: KANAAN. Removal success or error status: 0.
```

I don't see any error in the log file

Anyone has faced a similar error?

Note: I have created an empty project for demo purposes, and uninstall was called!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating a new setup project. Now Uninstall method is called.